# library 'class-transformer' select and apply class type to property of nested object

Tags: json, typescript, class-transformer

Given the following classes:

```
class A {
    items!: B;
}

class B {
    ...
}
```

how can I use the library class-transformer to directly apply the class types to following json:

```
{
    "items": {
        "b": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

basically the object of class B is comming "wrapped" inside another object just statiting "b", and I want to extract the content of the B class from that json

right now this is what I can get:

```
export class A {
    @Transform(({value}) => value.b)
    @Expose()
    items!: B
}
```

but when checking the type of the "items" property it's not defined, it's just "Object"

am I missing something? This seams possible to achieve, but I am stuck.

Note: The json structure is badly done, but at the moment it's not possible for me to update the way it's generated, so I need to handle the situation on the frontend side

Thanks in advance